# AngularJs passing parameters to a service

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to input Id via post method and get data for that Id back from database. I'm currently getting an error "employeeID is not defined" in my controller code.

**Controller code:**

```
$scope.employeeID = '10';


function test() {
    var getData = myService.getEmployee(employeeID);
    getData.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees2 = emp.data;

    }, function () {
        alert('Error in getting records');
    });
}

test(employeeID);
```

**Service code:**

```
this.getEmployee = function (employeeID) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Home/getEmployeeByNo",
        params: {
            id: JSON.stringify(employeeID)
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

**HomeController code:**

```
    public JsonResult getEmployeeByNo(string EmpNo)
    {
        using (InsiteEntities dataContext = new InsiteEntities())
        {
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(EmpNo);
            var employeeList = dataContext.Employee.Find(no);
            return Json(employeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

From

```
 var getData = myService.getEmployee(employeeID);
```

To

```
 var getData = myService.getEmployee($scope.employeeID);
```

Comment: where are you getting inside function test?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `EmpNo` parameter inspite of `id` parameter in `params` object, so that the URL will form like `Home/getEmployeeByNo?EmpNo=123`

```
this.getEmployee = function (employeeID) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Home/getEmployeeByNo",
        params: {
            EmpNo: employeeID //changed to `EmpNo`
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

Also pass `employeeID` from `$scope` as describe in [**`Sajeeth's answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053690/2435473) like `myService.getEmployee($scope.employeeID);`

Comment: @neela mark this answer as correct, if it helped, Thanks ;)